# Add computer to Azure AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

I have Office 365 for my organisation, with Azure AD.
How can I integrate my office computers (windows10) itself to the Azure AD?

When I want to connect in Windows 10 to my business network
(settings -> make connection to work or school)
After I try to give my e-mail (office 365 account), I got an axtra field for Server address?

Does anyone know what this should be?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 E1 version was required to do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where its asking for a server address to be used. Have you used Azure AD Join? This will make the process of connecting those devices easier.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/05/28/azure-ad-join-on-windows-10-devices.aspx